# RMMapView map set region

Tags: ios, dictionary, region, mapbox

I have to set my offline map that has been constructed with tilemill centralized on a custom point. Although i did not find a method like setRegion for MKMapView to make this job for me. Is there any way to set region to a rmmapview map?

Answer (score 1):

no, regions like in ios are not available in route-map. you can set constraints, so that the user cant scroll out of your map:

```
// Constrain our map so the user can only browse through our exported map tiles
[self.mapView setConstraintsSW:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapSrc.bottomRightOfCoverage.latitude, self.mapSrc.topLeftOfCoverage.longitude)
                       NE:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapSrc.topLeftOfCoverage.latitude, self.mapSrc.bottomRightOfCoverage.longitude)];
```

and of course scrolling to specific position:

```
[self.mapView moveToLatLong:self.currentPosition.coordinate];
```

Comment: moveToLatLong method doesn't exist according to compiler. Is this a method that i have to make by own? Furthermore, when i call setConstraintsSW method i get bad access of memory error.

Comment: i used it with ios6, dont know if it works with current ios/xcode version. i have the moveToLatLong method definition in RMMapView header file. did you use the lib from https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Comment: It has changed to moveToCoordinate method by MapBox API and includes in RMShape.h . I am going to check this lib and i will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue with the code below:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerOfMap = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

[mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerOfMap];
```

With this way i have every time my map centralized to the point that i want.
Also,someone can adjust the zoom of the map and reach the result that he wants.